# boost filesystem how to access shared folders

Tags: networking, boost, boost-filesystem, shared-directory

I'm looking for this and I couldnt find anything to help me. I think it is simple, what i need to do is to show the shared folders in my network, using boost libraries.

For example

```
std::string dir = "/home/user";
for (boost::filesystem::directory_iterator it(dir), end; it!=end; it++)
    if (boost::filesystem::is_directory(*it))
        cout << it->path().filename().generic_string();
```

This shows me all folders in the path `"/home/user"`. The question is, whats is the `dir` that i need to use to show my shared folders in my network? I try `"\\", "\\my_pc_name", "\\Workgroup"` but i have no idea and i don't know if i can do this in this way.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I assume from your question that you're on Linux and the folders you're trying to access are on a Windows share. You can't access them directly -- you'll need to mount them using something like smbfs. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381143/transparent-access-to-files-on-samba-shares-on-linux-et-al-using-c-io-streams) for more.

Comment: Yes, i'm on Linux and trying to access on a Windows share, but i need too make this in Windows, but when i do this first. I'm looking for a way that works in Linux and Windows. Now i'm begining. Thanks for your answer, i'm seeing the link.

Comment: On Windows, you can access the path directly (or so [this link](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/50546/) says, I don't have a Windows box handy).

Comment: I saw in the file `/proc/mounts` that there are the mounted drives. If i mount a shared folder i can use this path with boost::filesystem and it works. Exist any way to mount the shared folder and use it in this way? I saw the command `mount` in C++ `<sys/mount.h>` but i dont know how to use it, and the system command `mount` need admin access to use it.

Comment: Sure. If you don't have root, try `smbnetfs`, as described here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/24348/how-do-i-mount-samba-share-as-non-root-user